# Extract mine only from file --mime-type to use in a if-else in bash script

Tags: bash, 20.10

I have found that this command gives me the mime type from a file:

```
file --mime-type dog.jpeg
```

Output:

```
dog.jpeg: image/jpeg
```

I am now trying to create a bash checks if the mime is jpeg og png. However I am a bit stuck:

```
#!/bin/bash
$file_mime="file --mime-type dog.jpeg"
mime=`"${file_mime#*:}"`

if(mime=='image/jpg' OR mime=='image/png') do:
    echo"Jpg or png"
done
```

Output:

```
./bash.sh: line 2: =file --mime-type dog.jpeg: command not found
./bash.sh: line 3: : command not found
```

Comment: Your `if` statement could be `if [[ $mime == 'image/jpg' || $mime == 'image/png' ]]; then echo "Jpg or png"; fi` - you can replace `;` with new lines.

Comment: You can tell `file` to omit the filename by adding the `--brief` or `-b` switch i.e. `file --brief --mime-type dog.jpeg`

Comment: you can make it in a single statement `[[ $mime = image/@(jpeg|png) ]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first error is because you have a `$` prefix on your assignment. Your second error is because you are trying to combine the execution of the command with the processing of the results (stripping the filename from the result). As always with bash scripting there are lots of ways to achieve the same thing so this is just one, try:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mime=$(file -b --mime-type dog.jpeg)

if [[ $mime = image/@(jpeg|png) ]]; then
    echo "File is a jpeg or png."
fi
```

Then evaluate `$mime` but I suggest you search and read up on some bash scripting tutorials for `if` statements etc as your `if` statement is not valid bash script.

Comment: I would use the new style command substitution, and would put the command directly inside `result="$(file --mime-type dog.jpeg)"`, or: `file='dog.jpeg'; result="$(file --mime-type "$file")"`.

Comment: you use should skip string manipulation altogether just do `file -b --mime-type $file`

Comment: bash: [[ expression ]] "the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the  rules  described  below  under *Pattern Matching*, as if the extglob shell option were enabled."

Comment: Hope this is not a version thing?

Comment: @bac0n ah OK ...

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of variables in bash is *without* the dollar sign `$`:

```sh
var="foo"
echo "$var"
foo
```

Now you want to perform a command substitution, the `file` variable being the result of the command `file --mime-type dog.jpeg`. The way to do it is:

```sh
# now the output of the command is stored in the variable
file_mime=$(file --mime-type dog.jpeg)
```

Now you can echo the variable:

```sh
echo "$file_mime"
dog.jpeg  image/jpeg
```

and to get the mime type:

```sh
mime=$(echo "$file_mime" | awk '{ print $2 }')
echo "$mime"
image/jpeg
```